# using Leaflet Remove a geojson layer that came from an ajax jquery result

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, leaflet

I have a MySQL database with a table containing a polygon geometry.
I have a Leaflet map that post the coordinates of where you click, run a SQL query to select the polygon that contains the coordinates. Another php file then echo a geojson, that I use to add to the leaflet map.

This works very well, however no matter what I do I can't remove these features. Every time I click on a new area a new polygon is added and the old one isn't removed. Below is a link to a youtube video of what I'm getting. Saying that in the video removeLayer() if defined in a function outside of the ajax function that gets the geojson. But no matter where I put removeLayer() I can't remove any old feature when adding a new one.

https://youtu.be/1idIc7ROXE0

So below is the js script.

In short this is what I'm doing.

Step 1. I get the coordinates when clicking on the map, transform it to WKT to be used in MySQL, send the WKT to the function that will get the data

Step 2. Here I use an ajax function to post the WKT to php that will first drop all the data in a temporary table and insert the new info for the polygon that contains the coordinates from the WKT.

Step 3. I select * from the temporary table, echo the info as a geojson.

```
 //step 3----------------get the geojson from the MySQL table-----
    function getBuilding(n) {
    var getBuildingSelected_jq = $.ajax({
      url: "phpfile_selected.php",
      data: "q=1"+n,
      dataType:"json",
      async: false,
      success: function(data){

          console.log("getting clicked polygon")
      }
    }).responseText;

     var convert_ = JSON.stringify(eval("(" + getBuildingSelected_jq + ")"))
     var selectedBuildingLayer2 = JSON.parse(convert_);

     var selectedBuildingLayer2 = L.geoJSON(selectedBuildingLayer2)
     selectedBuildingLayer2.addTo(map)
     }
```

//step 2----------------post the coord to the php file and do the sql query-----

```
    async function php_postCoord(clicked)
            {
            var site = clicked;
            $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:'PHP_postCoordToMySQL.php',
                data: {Site:site},                 
                success: function(value){
                console.log('yes');
                }
            });
                await sleep(250)
              //-----refresh totals----
                $("#divSq_m").load(" #divSq_m");

                map.removeLayer(selectedBuildingLayer2)
                getBuilding(1);
          };
```

//step 1---------------------on map click get the coord's and make a WKT from it, run functions to post the data and get the data form mysql.

```
      map.on('click', async function (e) {
     var lnglat = [e.latlng.lat, e.latlng.lng];
    console.log(lnglat)

    //---make WKT Yes I know there are better ways to do this, but hay this workd for me
    latLng_ = lnglat.reverse()
    latLng_ = JSON.stringify(latLng_);
    var i = 0;
            while (i <100)   {
                     latLng_= latLng_.replace("[","");
                        latLng_= latLng_.replace(","," ");
                            latLng_= latLng_.replace("]","");
                i++;
            }
    console.log(latLng_)

    var start = "POINT("; //the start of the string that need to be send to SQL  
    var end = ")"; //the last but of the string that need to be send to SQL
    s = start.concat(latLng_.concat(end)); // concat the first bit, middle part and last bit

    console.log(s)

    php_postCoord(s)
```

OK so here is the php script that get's the coord's and do the sql query. (PHP_postCoordToMySQL.php)

```
<?php require_once('connect.php');
$idXY = $_POST["Site"];
$query = "delete from _building";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);

$query ="insert into _building ( sq_m,geojson_text ) 
SELECT    sq_m,geojson_text  FROM  demo_data_buildings  
WHERE 
ST_Contains(SHAPE, ST_GeomFromText('".$idXY."',1))";
$result = mysqli_query($con, $query);
```

Here is the php file that is called and returned a geojson from the results above (phpfile_selected.php).

```
require_once('connect.php');


$myquery = "SELECT build.* FROM demo_data_buildings as build join _building as b on b.gti_id = build.gti_id";

$result = mysqli_query($con, $myquery);
//echo -----the geojson------";
echo "{
\"type\": \"Feature\",
\"name\": \"Buildings\",
\"crs\": { \"type\": \"name\", \"properties\": { \"name\":
\"urn:ogc:def:crs:OGC:1.3:CRS84\" } },
\"features\": [";

while ($row =mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    $sq_m = $row['sq_m'];
    $geoj = $row['geojson_text'];
    echo  "{ \"type\": \"Feature\", \"properties\":{\"sq_m\":".$sq_m."},\"geometry\": ".$geoj."},";
};
echo "]}";
```

I get the suspicion this has to do with something like, the layer only exists in a function or something that I don't understand when it comes to jquery ajax.
Any way thank!!!!

Comment: What's the value of `selectedBuildingLayer2` when you're doing `map.removeLayer(selectedBuildingLayer2);` ??

Comment: Thanks for your comment. You made me realist what I'm doing wrong. I'm truly an idiot. See my comment.

Answer (score 0):

so I feel like an idiot.

I got the answer thanks to the comment from IvanSanchez.

In the code I posted I didn't indicate that I declare a global variable before the code like this: "var selectedBuildingLayer2"

Now this is what I did wrong. In the function that get's the geojson I declare selectedBuildingLayer2 again as "var selectedBuildingLayer2"

So basically I overwrite the global variable in the function so it can't be accessed outside the function.

A whole day of frustration and fighting only to see that that is the problem.

Thanks!!